# PHP Routing - stylesheets have no effect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, routes, stylesheet

I have created a basic Routing-system in PHP. The url is split into an array, so that i can decide what to show depending on the URL (ex: www.domain.com/page/option/param).

So in my index.php I've defined a div for header, content and footer, and the /page/ determines which file to include in the content-div. The routing works, and the HTML is loaded, but the stylesheet doesn't seem to be. Neither does it work when I `<link>` the stylesheet directly in the file (and supposedly it's possible to link a stylesheet within the body, with the attribude `itemprop`
rather than `rel`) - anyways, does anyone know what could be causing this?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My routing uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the URL, and i then remove the /index and split the rest into an array - all of this works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your <head> tag and see if the <style> tag is correct

Comment: It is.. If i run domain.com/index.php, or domain.com/, it loads the index.php just fine.

Comment: I mean't ... post here what are your url and whatis in head when css does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most rewriting of "fake" or friendly URL's, you need to specify the location of the stylesheet either using `absolute path` or using the `base` tag in the `head` section.

e.g.

```
<base href="http://example.com" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
//The CSS file above will load from http://example.com/css/style.css
```

OR

You can add a back slash before the path in the link tag so that it starts at the root directory.

```
<link href="/path/to/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thank you! The base tag worked. Can this fix be done within .htaccess? I know there's something called RewriteBase..

Comment: RewriteBase is just to tell .htaccess what directory prefix to use when processing the rules.  By default it's the root directory or `/`.  So that's why you don't need to specify it in your rules. It won't help the css issue.