# htaccess for SEO friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess

So for two days I can not understand why this won't work...:

```
  Options -Indexes 
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2
```

Obviously .htaccess is allowed since I am not able to directory open folders, but why doesn't the link work?

Comment: Please provide more info about your environment. Which URL do you test, what happens?
You may want to test a simple RewriteRule first, like 
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/test1.php?redirected=$1 [L,R]`

Comment: Please raise the log level to see if and how Apache processes this rule. Referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14793481/1163786

Comment: I am testing: domain.com/book/name-of-the-book/2 which should respond to book.php?book=name-of-the-book&id=2 but it says:

Not Found

The requested URL /book/name-of-the-book/2/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Where are the rules placed? Is it inside server config? Or inside an htaccess file? If the latter, please tell the location of the htaccess file too.

Comment: They are placed in a .htaccess files in the /www/(/public_html) directory in a remote server in a hosting company.

Comment: Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2 [L]

This now worked, but when I type /advice/newadvice/2 it won't load any styles, but when I open /advice.php?advice=newadvice&id=2 it fully loads as it should.

Comment: "I am testing: domain.com/book/name-of-the-book/2" - Your directive in .htaccess clearly relates to a different URL format? Any additional information, you should edit and add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off `multiviews` so the server doesn't try and search for that as a file. In addition add the conditions so that it knows it's not looking for a real file or directory it's trying to serve and make the trailing slash optional.

```
  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Tried that:

Not Found

The requested URL /advice/test-advice-name/2/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: are you 100% positive .htaccess is enabled? Add garbage at the top of the file and if you get a 500 error its enabled. otherwise not and you need to edit the config and change `AllowOverride None to` `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2 [L]

This now worked, but when I type /advice/newadvice/2 it won't load any styles, but when I open /advice.php?advice=newadvice&id=2 it fully loads as it should.

Comment: to fix the CSS styles add `<base href="http://www.example.com" />` to the head section of your html.

Comment: the rules work, now just add the css fix I mentioned and let me know.

Comment: I added <base href="http://www.example.com" /> right before the <title> tag in the <head>, but it still won't load the styles, though it fully loads when I use the .php url. Also, the <base> tag doesn't show in the view page source window.

Comment: @TsvetilinBoynovski Can you provide one example from your code where you link the stylesheet? (The one which does not load). Only put the `<link ...` tag.

Comment: @TsvetilinBoynovski I'm not sure what you're doing, but either adding the base tag or using a slash in front of your link **will work**. `<link href="/path/to/style.css">` http://stackoverflow.com/a/32913668/330987 Make sure it's exactly the way I mentioned. There is no semi colon in there.

Comment: @PanamaJack   Here's an example for the included stylesheet based in header.php, which gets included in each page from my website:  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @PanamaJack Sorry dude, I had some problem with the deployment in phpstorm, everything's alright now!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `RewriteRule` redirect to an existing file?
Try this, it works for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /test2/test.php
```

- `http://example.com/test2/.htaccess` shows the location of the `.htaccess` file
- `http://example.com/test2/test.php` is a direct link
- `http://example.com/test2/testX4XX` opens the same test.php file using rewrite

Comment: Works with this now:

  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2 [L]

but when I type in the browser /advice/newadvice/2 it doesn't load the styles, it just shows plain text as it comes from the sql and the html, although when I open advice.php?advice=newadvice&id=2 it loads as it should with all the styles.

Comment: @Tsvetilin Not loading the styles, may be due to the path referencing the styles. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> may need to be <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css">