# How to change directory root for review/testing

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, directory, subdirectory, document-root

I currently have a domain as

```
www.my-domain.co.uk
```

and I have a testing/review area set-up as

```
www.my-domain.co.uk/review/sitename
```

However I have set-up my navbar as the following:

```
<a href="/our-work/">Our Work</a></li>
<a href="/help-for-you/">Help For You</a></li>
<a href="/how-to-apply/">How To Apply</a></li>
<a href="/support-us/">Support Us</a></li>
<a href="/donate/">Donate Now</a></li>
```

Now in testing on localhost this would be fine -

But under `www.my-domain.co.uk/review/sitename`. The links go back to the root index.html file.

I've looked around but haven't found a direct answer and can't figure it out. Is there a way to change the root via the .htaccess file so it thinks that the `/review/sitename` is the root? Or do I have to change all those links?

Comment: Show your current htaccess

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to organize your site and links but you can do something like this. This would go in the .htaccess in the root and you're files are in the `/review/sitename` location.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /review/sitename/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I may just have to organise my links, since it doesn't work with the css. And I can't have multiple reviews up at the same time doing this.

Comment: You can fix the CSS easily

Comment: to fix the CSS styles add `<base href="http://www.example.com" />` to the head section of your html http://stackoverflow.com/a/32913668/330987